# How to practise coding in java with eclipse without creating a new class each time

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning java.
while i was learning C++ i used to copy codes from tutorial to code::block and play with it.
but in java with eclipse i have to create a new class each time, so that it matches the code.
is there a way so that i could copy past the code in eclipse and run it without changing the file name.
or any other tip to go around the problem.
what do others do, who are also learning java and  trying different codes in eclipse.

Comment: you can just change the class name to match your file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Scrapbook page. https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm?cp=1_3_7